# Font rendering improves when element placed in front of a Google Map with z-index

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, rendering, z-index, google-font-api

I have an element common to all pages that uses a font called "Just Another Hand" provided by Google Fonts API. On one of my pages, the element coincidentally happens to load in front of a Google Map and I noticed that when this happens the font rendering changes to a more eye-pleasing, fuzzier but smoother appearance (see screenshots below). I am using Chrome v.29 on Windows 8.

Further observations: Notice the grey header text (also visible in screenshot) does not change dependent on the presence of a Google Map. Use the inspector to remove the z-index property and the font rendering will return to it's original, less eye-pleasing state. The element has to be in front of the Map for any effect to happen.

Why is this happening and can I leverage one of the technologies to force/suppress this effect?

P.S. I appreciate this is not a coding question by I am hoping it will receive a coding answer.

[image: Screenshot of page without a Google Map behind element]

[image: Screenshot of page with a Google Map behind element]

Comment: Heh... funny. It's not just the font, also the edges of the yellow rectangle that are smoother.

Comment: So it's been a few days and no answers. I even Tweeted @GoogleMapsAPI requesting they take a look but nothing. I just want to say (even if I am yelling into a cavernous abyss of deafness) that this is still very much a live unanswered question and if anyone can give me even some pointers to some docs I would very grateful.

Comment: Well. Maybe not enough helpful, but I saw same situation in other places in Firefox. My understanding is that rendering mechanism is doing more processing when it detects background of it won't be changing.